# Problem with cutting outline of circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I've tried to cut the outline of a circle, by using the knife tool, the shaper tool, all of the pathfinder tools(for example: minus back), and I couldn't find a way, to cut those lines correctly.

And this is the result whenever I try to cut this shape:
[image]

When I'm using the clipping mark tool, its making the background to be much bigger then it should:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  clipping mask.

Create a rectangle above the curves, select it together with the curves, open "Object > Clipping Mask> Create Clipping Mask". Problem solved.

[image]

Comment: when i export the picture, to png for example, it has more background then it should have

Comment: Use file > save for web, don't use Export

Comment: @Argaman put a arboard around the size you need then you can specify export of that.

Comment: @joojaa I tested here, it exports the whole object if using File > Export. So it's artboard + save for web

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use Object > Expand on the curved sections to turn them into a filled shape. Then you can use the Pathfinder "Intersect" function to trim them.

[image: Screenshot using Pathfinder "Intersect"]